# jQuery .on with angular elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I have this angular produced element:

```
<div ng-if="req.Expanded" ng-click="req.Expanded = false">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down drill-item cursor" 
       title="Get Details" data-req-id="{{req.Id}}"></i>
</div>
```

It expands a sibling element below showing drill down information.

On ready I set it up like this:

```
$('.drill-item').on('click', function(event) {
    alert('drilled!');
    $.post(
        ...
    );
});
```

That .on() method fires just fine the first time around, but when the angular calls remove the div with the ".drill-item" class and add a new one the anonymous callback never fires.

If I set up a function to dynamically call .on() after every time angular changes the objects it works, but it seems like a hack because .on() is supposed to work with content that wasn't originally loaded, right?

1) Why does this seem to fail for me unless I call .on() again?

2) What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `.on() is supposed to work with content that wasn't originally loaded` wrong

Answer (score 2):

Create a Function in your Controller

```
 $scope.MyFunction = function () {
     alert('drilled!');
    // Do something

};
```

Use attribute ng-click

```
<div ng-click="MyFunction()"
```

Answer (score 0):

During first load you binds the event handler directly to the element. The event will not fire for any elements added later. You can try

```
$(document).on('click', '.drill-item', function(event) {
    alert('drilled!');
    $.post(
        ...
    );
});
```